# VS Express 2015 for a rookie is ok?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I just bought a book of C / C++ you learn from scratch how to script , and I want to know if it's ok to use VS 2015 Express as a rookie

Thanks

Comment: That does depend a lot on what kind of application are you trying to develop. It is full of resources, so you might waste a lot of time wondering around on then.

Comment: IMO: If you want to learn, you do not need an IDE as massive as Visual Studio. I'd recommend Code::Block, then when the need arise (when you need to make application in say Windows Forms/WPF - Visual Studio, Qt or others), you'll upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Martin, I'll start with Code :: Blocks